# why read in bash seems to write on the standard input

Tags: bash, stdin

i'm really confuse i don't know what's going on, so i'm not sure what to ask :/

i was going to use [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493578/how-to-send-d-eot-character-to-stdin-of-a-shell-process/493684#493684) to send input to the standard input of a program, in a bash script (i want `program.c` to read on stdin and print what it reads, i do that with readline without trouble, and i want `scrit.sh` to send to stdin what `program.c` will read, and i was doing it in a complicated way, when i realized that a while loop with `read` in the middle of my code was already accomplishing this task, and i don't know why !)

so it works without me sending anything intentionally to the STDIN (i do obviously, but it was not my intention when writing this loop), but i don't understand what's going on

here is how it looks : i use a bash script to call a program.c, which use readline to read the stdin and print it. The script.sh i wrote below should absolutely not work for what i understant (not much), but it does (almost) !

*program.c :*

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *line_input;

    line_input = readline("[myPrompt]> ");
    if (!line_input)
    {
        write(1, "exit\n", 5);
        exit(0);
    }
    write(1, line_input, strlen(line_input));
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

*script.sh :*

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="\
one
two"

while read -r line
do
    echo "line: $line"
    ./program
done < <(echo "$VAR")
```

and the output :

```
line: one
[myPrompt]> two
two
[myPrompt]> exit
```

so the word `two` is written to the right of `[myPrompt]>` , i guess the stdin, and it's executed by `./program.c`

why ? i never sent it, i just called `./program` in the while loop of the script, but it don't send anything to stdin

and why does it start at the second word ?

i can't reproduce this behavior if i don't use read in my loop, so it could be related

Comment: Did you really execute `./program.c`? You can't execute C source code, you need to compile it.

Comment: `why ? i never sent it` What do you think `< <(echo "$VAR")` means? `why does it start at the second word ?` because `read -r line` reads the first line. I think you may be missing the fact, that `while stuff1; do stuff2. done < this_here` redirects stdin for `stuff1` but _also_ for `stuff2` - the stuff inside the loop has also stdin connected to the redirection.

Comment: @Barmar ho, it's a mistake ! i'll edit my question ;) (`./program.c` -> `./program`)

Comment: @KamilCuk indeed i was completely missing this fact :) you explained everything in a comment, that could be the accepted aswer

Answer (score 3):

`< <(echo "$VAR")` uses process substitution to redirect the standard input of the loop to the output of the `echo "$VAR"` command. It affects the entire loop, not just the `read -r line` line.

`./program` inherits `stdin` from this, so it also reads from the process substitution. `read -r line` reads the first line, then `readline()` in `./program` reads the second line.

And because `readline()` is intended for interactive input, it echoes the input as it's reading it. That's why you see it on the prompt line, where you would see it if you were responding interactively.

If you want the program to read from the terminal rather than the input redirection, you can redirect it to `/dev/tty`:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="\
one
two"

while read -r line
do
    echo "line: $line"
    ./program </dev/tty
done < <(echo "$VAR")
```

You can also save the original stdin that the script inherited, and redirect to that.

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR="\
one
two"

while read -r line
do
    echo "line: $line"
    ./program.c <&3
done 3<&0 < <(echo "$VAR")
```

BTW, instead of using process substitution, you can use a here-string: `<<<"$VAR"`

Comment: cool tips, the here-string :)

Comment: thx ! it explains clearly why `program.c` only read the second line ! but it misses the explanation of why `program.c` something on stdin (as explained by @KamilCuk comments) (now that i understand what `< <("$VAR")` does, it seems obvious, but it wasn't when i asked), if you add that i could mark it as the accepted answer :)

btw, my question was unclear, i edited it, i knew why `program.c` was printing a prompt and the command when it receives something on stdin, but i didn't understand why it received it (which is what i want) !

Comment: I've added a first paragraph to the answer, does that answer your question?

Comment: that's better yes, thx, and @KamilCuk added an important point : the redirection of stdin happens on the whole loop, its conditions and its content, i think this is important to understand what is going on ?